# Help identifying a herb scented similar to thyme in Australia

Tags: identification, herbs

I've been given a cutting of a herb to grow and it has a similar smell to thyme which I'm using for recipies which need thyme.

I'm in Australia, New South Wales and haven't been able to identify it.

Has a similar scent to Thyme or Rosemary.

[image: thyme or rosemary smelling herb]

Comment: Thyme and rosemary smell completely different,but you're essentially saying this has aromatic leaves - I don't recognise the leaf parts in the picture, any chance of a picture of the main plant?

Comment: Plectranthus amboinicus http://dtlherbsltd.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/herb-of-week-cuban-oregano.html

Answer (score 3):

After looking closely at the leaf, it appears to be a succulent type herb which has always been called Cuban oregano. If you've moved to a new climate/zone, I always find the best nursery in the area, and make them my new best friends!